# How to Clean space in /home dir Ubuntu from Spark remains?

Tags: scala, ubuntu, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I run Spark, Scala in Intellij IDEA, in Ubuntu 16.04.
Every time i run a project in Intellij my /home dir in Ubuntu gets shorter and shorter!!! 
My /home dir is running out of space: it has only 221MB left!
Does anyone know how can i clean at least the trash from every run which are created in my /home dir? (Where they are might be?)

```
:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1,9G     0  1,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           392M  6,3M  386M   2% /run
/dev/sda5        42G  4,6G   35G  12% /
tmpfs           2,0G  496K  2,0G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           2,0G     0  2,0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda4       2,9G  2,5G  221M  92% /home
tmpfs           392M  104K  392M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda2       240G   90G  150G  38% /media/spartan/96AC55620C55F11A
```

/dev/sda2 has Windows. Is there any way to add more space from /dev/sda5 which is the /.

- I have created a Symlink from /home/secondary(a folder i created) to /home2. But that didn't enlarged my /home dir at all!

I want a quick (draft) solution if possible for the time being. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options you can use to control where and how Spark's local data gets written and when it gets deleted:

1. Set `spark.local.dir` to some folder on a drive with more space (e.g. `/media/spartan/96AC55620C55F11A` in your case). That would make Spark write all of its local data into that folder.
2. Assuming you're using standalone mode, you can also control if/when Spark executors cleanup their local data (see details [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html)):

   - set `spark.worker.cleanup.enabled` to `true`
   - set `spark.worker.cleanup.interval` to something short enough (shorter than your average application uptime), e.g. `120` (2 minutes)
   - set `spark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl` to something short enough (e.g. `3600` to keep files for one hour)
3. Make sure that you *stop* the spark session (e.g. `sparkContext.stop()`) every time before shutting down the application - some files are deleted immediately during proper shutdown and won't be deleted if JVM is just killed before the session is stopped

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will make a try.